# Relative output directory for Object File Name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, c++-modules

[image]

If I change `Object File Name` from `$(IntDir)` to `$(IntDir)%(RelativeDir)`, Visual Studio gives the following error when compiling:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1016,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "C:\Source\Repos\Smia\DpGraphs\out\x64\Debug\C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32522\modules". The given path's format is not supported.
```

`C:\Source\Repos\Smia\DpGraphs\out\x64\Debug\` is my `$(IntDir)`. It seems that Visual Studio wants to compile some file inside `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32522\modules`, and `%(RelativeDir)` is calculated to the full path since it is not relative to my project.

I'm using C++ modules in my project, so that's probably why a file on that path is compiled.

I have files with the same names in my project, so I'd like to keep `%(RelativeDir)` in the `Object File Name`.

How can I solve this? I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.6.0 Preview 4.0.

**Edit 1**

Here is my project file. As you can see, I'm not including all files using relative paths, so I think the file causing the issue must be included by one of the `<import Project"..." />` lines.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{bda3f5fc-e66c-4c4c-a540-6432a8b2a847}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpplatest</LanguageStandard>
      <ObjectFileName>$(IntDir)%(RelativeDir)</ObjectFileName>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\DirectedGraph.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\Edge.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\Edge.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\Graph.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\Graph.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\GraphTypes.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\Node.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="DirectedGraph\Node.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\Edge.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\Edge.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\Graph.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\Graph.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\GraphTypes.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\NestableGraph.ixx" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\Node.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="NestableGraph\Node.ixx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Edit 2**

I was able to find out which files are included by full path:

- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32522\modules\std.ixx.obj`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32522\modules\std.compat.ixx.obj`

**Edit 3**

I've tried explicitly including the two files causing issues in my project file. The idea was that I could then override `Object File Name` for only those files. But then the files are just included twice and the issue persists.

Comment: We can't see the project file.  So fix it the other way: right-click one of the trouble source files (the source file, not the project) > Properties > C/C++ > Output Files > "Object File Name" = $(IntDir)foo.obj.  Collision avoided.

Comment: That would have been a great solution if I had control of over including the file causing the issue. I've included my project file so you can see that it's not in there.

Comment: On further investigation I discovered that it is `std.ixx` and `std.compat.ixx` that are causing the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be disabling `Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules`:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in latest MSVC (does not happen with 14.35, but does with 14.36) - Did you find a bug report somewhere by chance?

Comment: I did not have a look. Please comment here if you find one.

Answer (score 3):

On Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 1.0, disabling *Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules* doesn't seem to be enough anymore. The workaround I found was to add `<EnableStdModules>false</EnableStdModules>` to any top-level `<PropertyGroup>` inside the project file or a property sheet.

For example, at the top of the project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <EnableStdModules>false</EnableStdModules>
    </PropertyGroup>

    [... rest of the file]
```

### For future reference

The error I get is:

> 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1016,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "C:\some\directory\C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.32919\modules". The given path's format is not supported.

There's two properties available from the UI for projects/property sheets:

- *Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules*, which sets `<BuildStlModules>true</BuildStlModules>`
- *Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules*, which sets `<EnableModules>true</EnableModules>`

I enabled diagnostic verbosity for MSBuild to figure out where the directory gets added to the list of directories that need to be created: Tools menu, Options; expand Project and Solutions/Build And Run, set *MSBuild project build output verbosity* to `Diagnostic`.

I searched for `14.38.32919\modules` in the build output and found this:

```
1>Target "ComputeStdModulesCompileInputs" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets":
1>  Set Property: EnableStdModules=true
1>  Added Item(s): LibraryManifests=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.32919\modules\modules.json
```

Notice the `EnableStdModules=true`, which doesn't correspond to either property from the UI. Adding this property manually to the project file or a property sheet fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeDir` [is not *itself* necessarily a relative path](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4057). It's whatever the `Include` path attribute is set to. If the `Include` is absolute, so too will `RelativeDir` be.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. The problem is then that I'm not in control of the `Include` path since the file is not directly included by my project file, but probably by one of the included Visual Studio `.props` or `.targets` files. I've added my project file in my question so you can have a look.

Comment: On further investigation I discovered that it is `std.ixx` and `std.compat.ixx` that are causing the issues.